# Automatic connection to unknown WiFi-network (without user consent)

Tags: android

During a trip, I crossed one city. While crossing one area, I noticed that my phone was connected to an unknown WiFi access point:
[image]

I have never been in that place in my life, and have never connected to that AP. What trick does it uses to force my phone to connect to it?

Comment: Maybe you just had it in your pocket and due to some spurious random moves you caused a `screen on - swipe down - long press WIFI - connect to one of the networks`

Comment: I think this is redundant to Android SE.
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/64380/stop-wifi-connecting-to-open-networks

Comment: Perhaps your phone is configured to automatically connect to open hotspots?

Comment: @forest as I remember, I didn't have that turned on. btw, you can convert that to answer, i'll vote.

Comment: @T.Todua That was just a wild guess. I've never owned an Android device in my life.